# Изображения, сохданные с помощью BitmapFactory выглядят очень размытыми

Tags: android

Приложение получает изображения формата jpeg и размером 50х50 пикселей с сервера. делается это примерно так:

```
InputStream is = new URL(urlOfImage).openStream();

BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
myOptions.inScaled = false;
myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
myOptions.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
myOptions.inDither = false;
myOptions.inPurgeable = false;

image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, myOptions);
```

Также изображение затем выводится в ImageView размерами 50dp на 50dp. на экране устройства такое изображение выглядит размытым, не смотря на то, что физический размер картинки соответствует размеру скажем на экране компьютера.

Собственно опции битмапфактори пробовал разные, результат не меняется. Сталкивался ли кто с таким, что можно сделать, чтоб изображения рисовались нормально?

Comment: `50dp != 50px` - на современных аппаратах картинка Ваша "растягивается" при отрисовке. Лучшее решение - использовать альтернативные картинки для разных плотностей экранов или векторную графику. Либо пытаться самому подгонять картинку под плотность экрана при загрузке, подобрав наиболее оптимальные параметры.

Comment: @woesss, то есть мне нужно использовать .inScaled = true и соответственно inTargetDensity?